# Ajax call with parameter as local variables is not working

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, .net, ajax

I have defined a webMethod in code behind as follows.

```
 [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
        public static string testCall(int qid, String answerContent)
        {
        log.Debug("this is call from jquery" + qid.ToString() + answerContent);

            return "true";
        }
```

I am trying to call this method via ajax call in jquery as below.

```
<script>

         $(".submitBtn").click(function (e) {

             alert(this.id);
             var qID = this.id;

             $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: '/default.aspx/testCall',
                 data: '{ "qid":' + qID + ', "answerContent":"test" }',
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 success: function () {

                 },
                 failure: function (response) {
                     alert("fail");
                 },
                 dataType: 'html'
             });
         });
          </script>
```

But this is not working.

However is I pass hardcoded values for parameters as below, it works fine.

```
 data: '{ "qid":"1234", "answerContent":"test" }'
```

But with `var qID` passing as parameter not working

Comment: Test once with `data: JSON.stringify({ "qid":qID , "answerContent":"test" })`

Comment: i assume you are using Webforms right?

Comment: @Valkyriee Yes.

Comment: @Satpal. Still now working.

Comment: You've said your example at the end works, but `"1234"` is a `string`, not an `int`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes, it works with hard coded values.. but no when I pass variables.

Comment: @DKR: Something is going on that you haven't shown. Assuming you want to pass `this.id` as a *number* (despite your hardcoded version using a string), your original code would work (though it's not best practice). So something is going on that you haven't shown.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder. I have posted everything what I am working with. at serverside hardcoded values "1234" is parsable for int, may be thats why it worked. But yes I want to pass this.id which is not working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't hand-assemble JSON. You will get bitten by characters you don't expect in strings, you'll miss out delimiters, etc.

Instead, use the JSON stringifier:

```
data: JSON.stringify({qid: qID, answerContent:"test"}),
```

If the ID value is really a number (you're receiving it as an `int`), you'll want to parse it (as `this.id` is a string):

```
data: JSON.stringify({qid: +qID, answerContent:"test"}),
// ------------------------^
```

...but your hardcoded example that you said works uses a string for the ID, so...

Comment: I have posted everything what I am working with. at serverside hardcoded values "1234" is parsable for int, may be thats why it worked. But yes I want to pass this.id which is not working for me.

Comment: Okay I ifound it. "this.id"  doesnt have a integer value, thats why it was failing. My apologies. I changed parameter type to string and it worked. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You should use this line as:

```
data: '{ "qid": "' + qID + '", "answerContent":"test" }'
```

Comment: No, he/she really shouldn't.